# Issue Assigning Labels to the x axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a boxplot and trying to assigning labels to my x axis and this is the code I used:

```
tidy_titanic %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = as.logical(survived, labels("Died", "Survived")), y = fare))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_y_log10()
```

and I am getting error code:

```
Error in as.factor(survived, labels("Died", "Survived")) : 
  unused argument (labels("Died", "Survived"))
```

The labels end up in the x label rather than the plot itself.
any help to resolving this?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `x = factor(survived, labels = c("Died","Survived")) ...`? I think this might be a problem with the factor labeling.

Comment: `as.logical` doesn't take a `labels` argument - `factor` does.

Comment: But also, the default x axis label will be the column name, or whatever function of it you apply. Add to your plot `labs(x = "My x axis label")` to override the default.